# Time check function in extjs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to make an email form with extjs 4 that sends an email to 12000 company members at a time.

The server wouldnt hold that large number at one time, so im trying to write a function that generates the sending method every three messages or something.

Does anybody know of a suitable function? Sample code? Or a way to refresh an extjs form every few seconds/minutes/etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that's the best approach. But for refreshing a page it's basic javascript

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

and use a `setTimeout` to repeat the reload.

So a reload afther 5 seconds:

```
var t = setTimeout(function(){document.location.reload(true)}, 5000);
```

But I rather advice using an [ajax call](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) and a `setInterval` to repeat every x ms so you wouldn't have to reload any page at all!

An even cleaner approach is to handle it [on the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304049/how-to-send-a-secured-blast-email-to-thousands-users-in-php).

Another [helpful article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543153/is-there-a-limit-when-using-php-mail-function)

Another [helpful article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788596/whats-the-best-approach-to-sending-email-to-hundreds-of-recipients-from-a-zend)

Comment: @HashimSerag Btw welcome to StackOverflow ;) If you like an answer [you can accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and/or upvote it. If you have additional questions you can edit your answer or post it in comments. Glad I could help.

Comment: im really sorry im new ur right =)), i really like ur answer, i made it the ajax way n it was so helpful thank u so much, i've been working on it since i asked the question until now lol, thank u

Comment: You might also wish to check out [Ext.TaskManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.TaskManager), but as VDP suggested, I really don't think giving this task to a client javascript is a good thing - your backend should really do it using a queue / cron.